# How can I decrease opacity in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transparency, opacity

I see this subject in stack over flow but I think it is false
Making an object 'transparent' so it cannot be seen is not the most efficient way to do things. What you rather want to do is make the renderer inactive when you don't want to see it, and active when you do.

If you click on your `gameObject` in the editor, there should be a Mesh Renderer as one of the components.

To set it to inactive from a script attached to this same `gameObject`, you can do this...

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;
```

If you really want to use transparency, you can do this...

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color.a = 0;
```

Although if you are setting transparency, you need to make sure the shader the material is using supports transparency. I would suggest using the Legacy Shaders/Transparent Diffuse shader.

How I can use:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color.a = 0;
```

Answer (score 12):

For those who might still come across this question, `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color` is not a variable. Create a variable as such:

```
var trans = 0.5f;
var col = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color;
```

Then assign your value:

```
col.a = trans;
```

Also be aware that not all shaders have a `_Color` property. In my case, I had to use:

```
var col = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.GetColor("_TintColor");
```

Answer (score 2):

> How I can use:
>
> `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color.a = 0;`

As you already stated in your own question, the object you call this on must have a shader which supports transparency. In Unity5, when using the standard shader, you must explicitly set it to "Transparent" to be able to manipulate the alpha value.
[image]

It should also be clear to you that the alpha value is a `float` which goes from `0.0f` to `1.0f`, so e.g. setting

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color.a = 0.5f;
```

will make the object 50% transparent.

Comment: Hey, when I try this, it tells me that `color`'s `a` can't be changed -- is this answer still up-to-date?

Comment: According to http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-a.html this field *should* be changable since it's `public float a;`, are you sure you're using `UnityEngine.Color`? As a work-around, you can also re-construct the color doing `var color = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color; var newColor = new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, 0.5f); gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = newColor;`

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your material and change its **Rendering Mode** to `Transparent`.
2. Then, add the below script.

   using UnityEngine;

   public class MakeTransparent : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public GameObject currentGameObject;
       public float alpha = 0.5f;//half transparency

   ```
   void Start()
   {
       currentGameObject = gameObject;    
   }

   void Update()
   {
       ChangeAlpha(currentGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material, alpha);
   }

   void ChangeAlpha(Material mat, float alphaVal)
   {
       Color oldColor = mat.color;
       Color newColor = new Color(oldColor.r, oldColor.g, oldColor.b, alphaVal);
       mat.SetColor("_Color", newColor);

   }
   ```

   }

Change the alpha value in the inspector on runtime.

Here is the [**video explanation**](https://youtu.be/ALE9Z_wxavg).

Answer (score -4):

Try in this way

```
var other : GameObject;
other.renderer.material.color.a = 0.5f; // 50 % transparent
other.renderer.material.color.a = 1.0f; // 100% visible
```