# Unity - Change opacity of objects around selected one

Tags: unity-game-engine, transparency, collision

I would like to change the opacity of the objects that are "around" another object that i have selected by script ( GameObject.Find("MySelectedObject")) to have a "better visibility" of the selected one.

For example i could have a model of a car, i could have selected the engine and i would like to see it even if the hood is closed.

There is a way to achieve this goal? Can you give me some hints or point me to some functions or snippets?

Thanks for your time and , hopefully, answers;)

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit broad for SO, but basically you should 1) Scan for the objects in the scene and identify the near ones using Vector3.Distance. 2) Then, change their opacity: accessing their Material in order to modify the transparency (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415545/how-can-i-decrease-opacity-in-unity). Hope this helps...a more complex answer would be difficult, without some basic implementation.

Comment: You could have everything at low opacity and change it on [hover](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html) or something.

Comment: @JuanFerrer unfortunately my application uses ony touch screens